# bash - brace expansion not expanding?

Tags: bash, range, brace-expansion

On Kubuntu 15.10

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.42(1)-release
```

I try

```
reps=1
threads={1}{10..60..10}

for((r=0;r<$reps;r++))
do
    tCount=0
    for t in $threads
    do
        echo "t=$t, tCount=${tCount}"
        #do something funny with it
        ((tCount++))
    done
done
```

and it produces a single line

```
t={1}{10..60..10}, tCount=0
```

How do I get this to work?

**edit**

I expect

```
t=1, tCount=0
t=10, tCount=1
t=20, tCount=2
t=30, tCount=3
t=40, tCount=4
t=50, tCount=5
t=60, tCount=6
```

**update**

note that `threads=({1}{10..60..10})`

and then `for t in ${threads[@]}`

will prefix the `10..60..10` range with the string `{1}`

(i.e. `{1}10,{1}20,..,{1}60` )

Comment: I recommend to use `threads=$(echo {1}{10..60..10})`

Comment: @hek2mg This prefixes ``10,20,..,60`` with ``{1}`` (i.e. ``{1}10,{1}20,..,{1}60``. Which is also the reason why this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: The `{1}` is simply not required. What's the reason behind using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{1}` expression is just a string, since it doesn't conform to the brace expansion syntax:

> A sequence expression takes the form `{X..Y[..INCR]}`, where X and Y are either integers or single characters, and INCR, an optional increment, is an integer.

The brace expansion is performed *before* variable expansion, so you can't expand braces by just referring to a variable:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

Whether write the brace expansion directly, or use `eval` (usually not recommended).

Example:

```
tCount=0
for t in {1,{10..60..10}}; do
  echo "t=$t tCount=$tCount"
  (( tCount++ ))
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate on why ``eval`` is "usually not recommended"?

Comment: Command substitution should be used instead of `eval`: `threads=$(echo {10..60..10})`

Comment: @hek2mgl or in this case, ``threads=({1,{10..60..10}})``. Again, please elaborate on *why* this "should" be used.

Comment: That would produce an array.

Comment: @User1291, [much has been written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) regarding the bad `eval`, just read these posts.